# MySql - select random 4 data 2 different unique values from a column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I am trying a get a random dataset with 4 datas from t table with specific conditions.

I tried to choose 4 datas with conditions below

1. There must be 2 'Y' and 2 'C' datas from `f4` which are randomly chosen from dataset t table (it can be `Y-Y-C-C` or `C-Y-Y-C` or `C-C-Y-Y` etc)
2. There must be only one unique data of dataset distinct `f2` in that 4 data.

So it can be  `A-C-F-H` or `A-D-I-H` or `J-H-E-C`  etc.

I made this so far, but I cannot get 2 'C' and 2 'Y' on that 4 data.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76697b/23)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t ( id int, f2 char, f3 char, f4 char );
insert into t values
(1  ,'a'   ,'q'   ,'C'),
(2  ,'a'   ,'w'   ,'Y'),
(3  ,'b'   ,'e'   ,'C'),
(4  ,'b'   ,'r'   ,'Y'),
(5  ,'c'   ,'t'   ,'C'),
(6  ,'c'   ,'y'   ,'Y'),
(7  ,'d'   ,'u'   ,'C'),
(8  ,'d'   ,'o'   ,'Y'),
(9  ,'e'   ,'m'   ,'C'),
(10  ,'e'   ,'n'   ,'Y');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select f2, f3, f4
from (
 select f2, f3, f4
 from (
  select f2, f4, f3 from
   ( select f2, f4, f3
     from t
     order by rand()
   ) t0
  group by f2
 ) t1  
 order by RAND() 
) t2 order by rand()
 LIMIT 4
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76697b/23/0)**:

```
| f2 | f3 | f4 |
|----|----|----|
|  b |  r |  Y |
|  e |  n |  Y |
|  d |  o |  Y |
|  a |  w |  Y |
```

What I expect is ;

```
| f2 | f3 | f4 |
|----|----|----|
|  b |  r |  Y |
|  e |  n |  C |
|  d |  o |  C |
|  a |  w |  Y |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A brute force method:

```
select t1.id as id1, t2.id as id2, t3.id as id3, t4.id as id4
from t t1
join t t2 on t2.f2 not in (t1.f2)
join t t3 on t3.f2 not in (t1.f2, t2.f2)
join t t4 on t4.f2 not in (t1.f2, t2.f2, t3.f2)
where t1.f4 = 'C'
  and t2.f4 = 'C'
  and t3.f4 = 'Y'
  and t4.f4 = 'Y'
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/VNF93190

This query will return all possible row-id combinations. Choose one random combination in a subquery and join it with your table again to get the corresponding rows:

```
select t.*
from (
    select t1.id as id1, t2.id as id2, t3.id as id3, t4.id as id4
    from t t1
    join t t2 on t2.f2 not in (t1.f2)
    join t t3 on t3.f2 not in (t1.f2, t2.f2)
    join t t4 on t4.f2 not in (t1.f2, t2.f2, t3.f2)
    where t1.f4 = 'C'
      and t2.f4 = 'C'
      and t3.f4 = 'Y'
      and t4.f4 = 'Y'    
    order by rand()
    limit 1
) x
join t on t.id in (x.id1, x.id2, x.id3, x.id4)
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/GQCCO60910

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION` to get two `Y` and two `C`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT f2, f3, f4
    FROM t
    WHERE f4 = 'Y'
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 2) AS y
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT f2, f3, f4
    FROM t
    WHERE f4 = 'C'
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 2) AS c
```

But I'm not sure how to prevent these from having duplicate `f2` values between the two subqueries.